# Não consigo rodar um comando, com o pacote "rDEA"

Tags: r, data

Sou iniciante no R e não entendo boa parte das soluções em inglês. Creio, portanto, que um fórum em português possa me ajudar.

Tenho a seguinte base de dados (data):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou tentando rodar o comando:

```
## inputs and outputs for analysis
Y = data[c('V7', 'V8')]
X = data[c('V3', 'V4','V5','V6')]
W = data[('V2')]
## Naive input-oriented DEA score for the first 20 firms under variable returns-to-scale
firms=1:19
di_naive = dea(XREF=X, YREF=Y, X=X[firms,], Y=Y[firms,], model="input", RTS="variable")
di_naive$thetaOpt
## Naive DEA score in cost-minimization model for the first 20 firms under variable returns-to-scale
ci_naive = dea(XREF=X, YREF=Y, X=X[firms,], Y=Y[firms,], W=W[firms,],
model="costmin", RTS="variable")
ci_naive$XOpt
ci_naive$gammaOpt
```

Estou recebendo, contudo, a seguinte mensagem de erro:

```
> library("rDEA", lib.loc="~/R/win-library/3.3")
Using the GLPK callable library version 4.47
> data <- read.delim("~/R/win-library/3.3/data.txt", header=FALSE)
>   View(data)
> ## inputs and outputs for analysis
> Y = data[c('V7', 'V8')]
> X = data[c('V3', 'V4','V5','V6')]
> W = data[('V2')]
> ## Naive input-oriented DEA score for the first 20 firms under variable returns-to-scale
> firms=1:19
> di_naive = dea(XREF=X, YREF=Y, X=X[firms,], Y=Y[firms,], model="input", RTS="variable")
Error in dea.input(XREF = XREF, YREF = YREF, X = X, Y = Y, RTS = RTS) : 
  YREF has to be numeric matrix or data.frame.
> di_naive$thetaOpt
Error: object 'di_naive' not found
> ## Naive DEA score in cost-minimization model for the first 20 firms under variable returns-to-scale
> ci_naive = dea(XREF=X, YREF=Y, X=X[firms,], Y=Y[firms,], W=W[firms,],
+                model="costmin", RTS="variable")
Error in dea.costmin(XREF = XREF, YREF = YREF, X = X, Y = Y, W = W, RTS = RTS) : 
  YREF has to be numeric matrix or data.frame.
> ci_naive$XOpt
Error: object 'ci_naive' not found
> ci_naive$gammaOpt
Error: object 'ci_naive' not found
```

Comment: O erro está dizendo que o YREF precisa ser numérico (no seu caso é o objeto Y). Então, depois que vc criar a variável Y, rode este comando: Y <- as.numeric(Y), e me diga se o erro continua.

Answer (score 1):

O problema do seu código provavelmente está na importação dos dados.

A variável `Y` que você cria precisa ser um `data.frame` com colunas numéricas ou uma matriz numérica. No caso, pelo que pude ver pela imagem, ele está como `character`, por causa do símbolo de `º` que aparece depois do número.

Uma forma de corrigir isso é usar a função `parse_number` do apcote `readr`. Assim você pegaria só o valor numérico da variável e desconsideraria símbolo de `º` que está te atrapalhando.

Então, você pode transformar os seus dados antes fazendo assim:

```
library(readr)
data$V7 <- parse_number(data$V7)
data$V8 <- parse_number(data$V8)
```

Depois de rodar isso provavelmente vai funcionar. Se continuar aparecendo algum erro falando que alguma coluna não é numerica, procure problemas como esse em outras colunas da sua base.

Comment: Muito obrigado, rapaz!